# OSX: Always deny Google Chrome keychain password

Tags: google-chrome, osx-mountain-lion, keychain

Google Chrome v.22 will ask me when I visit sites if I want to allow it to be saved to my keychain.

There is Always Allow, Allow and Deny.  Where is Always Deny?  I hate typing in a particular website and it constantly asking me to Always Allow, Allow or Deny.

Comment: Similar: [Safari wants to access my keychain doesn't offer “always deny”](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/77174/22781) AD SE

Comment: Related: [How to stop Google Chrome’s annoying keychain access request messages](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/03/04/google-chrome-wants-to-use-your-confidential-information-store-in-the-keychain/)

Answer (score 3):

I found this http://kb.iu.edu/data/airp.html

I went to Apps > Utilities > Keychain Access and deleted the site that kept bothering me from the list.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution that allows you to always deny access, rather than just removing the password on a per-site basis?

Comment: Same here.  A pity that Chrome succeeds to make you stop using a Keychain it can't control.  Ditch chrome instead.